# webapp2 compatible templating system with tornadoweb style UIModule

Tags: google-app-engine, template-engine, webapp2

i have an app on GAE which for most of the application uses tornadoweb and its templating system.
for other handlers (specially BlobstoreHandlers) i use webapps builtin handlers which makes it easy to interact with GAE specific interfaces.

i would like to switch everything to webapp2 and use the new python2.7 runtime.

the only thing i miss is something like tornadowebs UIModules.
i can go a long way with jinja2 by using tags and filters but i miss something like UIModule.embedded_javascript(), UIModule.javascript_files(), UIModule.embedded_css() and UIModule.css_files() which embeds or adds the links to those files into the template.

is there something like this in another templating engine?